# Remove selected items from listWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlistwidget

How to remove selected items from a `QListWidget`?

I have tried write the following code, but it does not work.

```
QList<QListWidgetItem*> items = ui->listWidget->selectedItems();
foreach(QListWidgetItem item, items){
    ui->listWidget->removeItemWidget(item);
}
```

Comment: why item is not a pointer?

Comment: @wuqiang: I've changed `item` to `*item`. but still doesn't want to remove the items or any item.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

One way to remove item from `QListWidget` is to use `QListWidget::takeItem` which removes and returns the item :

```
QList<QListWidgetItem*> items = ui->listWidget->selectedItems();
foreach(QListWidgetItem * item, items)
{
    delete ui->listWidget->takeItem(ui->listWidget->row(item));
}
```

Another way is to `qDeleteAll` :

```
qDeleteAll(ui->listWidget->selectedItems());
```

Comment: Good answer. Please note that the example here for `qDeleteAll` is illustrative.... it deletes only the items selected in the UI. `qDeleteAll(ui->listWidget->items());` clears all entries. In general, `qDeleteAll(someListOfValidItems);` does the job.

Comment: Thank you, but the first way occurs an error `QModelIndex QListWidget::indexFromItem(QListWidgetItem*) const' is protected`.

Comment: @LionKing You are right. you should use `QListWidget::row`. The answer is updated.

Comment: @Youda008 `removeItemWidget` only removes the widget set on the item. To remove an entire row you should use `takeItem` and also delete it to free memory. See: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#removeItemWidget

Comment: @Nejat: That says manual. But i don't understand what `removes the widget set on the item` mean. What is `widget set` or what does it mean to `set widget on the item` ??

Comment: @Youda008 removeItemWidget only removes the widget and the result is that an empty item without widget is left.

Comment: @Youda008 To make removeItemWidget(item) work, you should add in the following line delete(item)

Comment: @Nejat - Your one-line answer (`qDeleteAll(ui->listWidget->selectedItems());`) is as relative today as it was when you gave it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

To give a solution with `removeItemWidget`:

```
QList<QListWidgetItem*> items = ui->listWidget->selectedItems();

foreach(QListWidgetItem* item, items){
    ui->listWidget->removeItemWidget(item);
    delete item; // Qt documentation warnings you to destroy item to effectively remove it from QListWidget.
}
```