# Remove QListWidgetItem: QListWidget::takeItem(item) vs delete item

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

To remove a given `QListWidgetItem* item` from a `QListWidget* lst` I can use following code ([taken from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25418363/1485885)):

```
delete lst->takeItem(lst->row(item)); // method 1
```

On the other hand, if I just destroy the item, it is also removed from the list (at least it *disappears* from the `QListWidget`).

```
delete item; // method 2
```

[`QListWidget` documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#details) indicates using `takeItem` but doesn't mention anything about deleting the item (`QListWidgetItem` doesn't have any information neither).

> To remove items from the list, use takeItem().

Is there any difference between using method 1 (`takeItem` and then delete it) and method 2 (directly delete the item)? Maybe a memory leak I'm missing, a signal that is not emitted, etc? I mean, it seems easier to just delete the item (if you have it, of course) rather than searching for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following line from the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#removeItemWidget) answers your question:

> To remove an item (row) from the list entirely, **either** delete the item **or** use `takeItem()`.

This means that there is no difference between taking the item then deleting it, or deleting it directly.

`takeItem()` just removes ownership from the item, so that you have the chance to do anything with it (maybe use it in another `QListWidget`). If you just want to remove the item, you can just delete it and the destructor will take care of removing ownership.

Comment: As `removedItemWidget` wasn't working for me I completely ignored it. Thanks for your quick answer @Mike.

Comment: You are welcome :) . [`removeItemWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#removeItemWidget) is not meant to remove the item from the `QListWidget`, it is there to remove a widget that has been previously set on item using [`setItemWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#setItemWidget).

Comment: Yes, when I read the documentation I got it, but the initial thought when I saw the name was that it removed the `QListWidgetItem` ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is a substantial semantic difference related to *returning or not* the removed item:

[docs say:](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#removeItemWidget)

> To remove an item (row) from the list entirely, either delete the item or use takeItem()

The final difference between [`takeItem`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qlistwidget.cpp.html#_ZN11QListWidget8takeItemEi) and [calling the destructor directly](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qlistwidget.cpp.html#_ZN10QListModel6removeEP15QListWidgetItem) will be in calling [`takeAt`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qlist.h.html#_ZN5QList6takeAtEi) instead of [`removeAt`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qlist.h.html#_ZN5QList8removeAtEi) and, in the first case, being able to return the removed item while in the latter you just discard the thing entirely (*take* doesn't delete the item, you do it later)

Comment: Thanks! As I already have the item `takeItem` adds nothing. It, of course, would be different if I'd only had the row index.

Comment: Hello everyone, I have a quick question about this post: What would be the opposite? Meaning, from a list in `QListWidget`, how can I keep a single item only and erase the rest?